# Get state of toggle button placed on header in app.view from other views

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I need to get state state of toggle button placed on header in `app.view` from other views. On app.view I have header and footer. Toggle button is on header. Button on press switch user role between *admin/user*. On other views I have buttons which on press opens external URL based on user role. Also I want to switch roles on every view. How to achieve that?

App.view.xml

```
<mvc:View 
    height="100%"
    controllerName="sap.ui5.App" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified">
        <Page 
            id="masterPage" 
            title=""
            showHeader="false"
            enableScrolling="false">
               <tnt:ToolHeader>
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <core:Icon src="sap-icon://tree" class="headerIcon" size="1.2rem"/>
                <Text text="Title" wrapping="false" class="headerText">
                    <layoutData>
                        <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Disappear" />
                    </layoutData>
                </Text>
            <ToolbarSpacer />
        <Button icon="sap-icon://home" type="Transparent" press="onHomePress">
                <layoutData>
                    <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
                </layoutData>
            </Button>
            <ToggleButton id="btnRoleSwitch"  icon="sap-icon://person-placeholder" enabled="true" pressed="false" press="onRoleSwitchPress" type="Transparent"/>
                <Label text=""/>
    </tnt:ToolHeader>
    <App id="rootControl" class="adjustedHeight"/>
        <footer>
            <Toolbar>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <Text text="Footer text" wrapping="false"></Text>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>
            </Toolbar>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

```html
<mvc:View 
     height="100%"
     controllerName="sap.ui5.App" 
     xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
     xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
     xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
     xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
     xmlns="sap.m"
     xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified">
      <Page 
       id="masterPage" 
       title=""
       showHeader="false"
       enableScrolling="false">
          <tnt:ToolHeader>
        <ToolbarSpacer />
        <core:Icon src="sap-icon://tree" class="headerIcon" size="1.2rem"/>
        <Text text="Title" wrapping="false" class="headerText">
         <layoutData>
          <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Disappear" />
         </layoutData>
        </Text>
       <ToolbarSpacer />
      <Button icon="sap-icon://home" type="Transparent" press="onHomePress">
        <layoutData>
         <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="NeverOverflow" />
        </layoutData>
       </Button>
       <ToggleButton id="btnRoleSwitch"  icon="sap-icon://person-placeholder" enabled="true" pressed="false" press="onRoleSwitchPress" type="Transparent"/>
        <Label text=""/>
     </tnt:ToolHeader>
     <App id="rootControl" class="adjustedHeight"/>
      <footer>
       <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
         <Text text="Footer text" wrapping="false"></Text>
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
       </Toolbar>
      </footer>
     </Page>
    </mvc:View>
```

App.controller.js

```js
return BaseController.extend("sap.ui5.App", {
      onInit : function () {

      },
     
      onDisplayNotFound: function(oEvent) {
       // display the "notFound" target without changing the hash
       this.getRouter().getTargets().display("notFound", {
        fromTarget: "home"
       });
      },

      onHomePress : function(oEvent) {
       this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("home");
      },
      
      onRoleSwitchPress : function (oEvent) {
       var modeInfoMessage;
       var oBtnRoleSwitch = this.byId("btnRoleSwitch");
       var btnState = oBtnRoleSwitch.getPressed();
       var sRole = "";
       
       if  (btnState == true) {
        sRole = "Admin";
        
       }
       else if (btnState == false) {
        sRole = "User";
       }
       
       MessageToast.show(sRole);
      }
     });

    }, true);
```

View1.controller.js

```js
return BaseController.extend("sap.ui5.View1", {
      onInit: function() {

       
      },
      
        
      
      onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
       var oTileUrl = "";  
       var oTileFunction = "";
       var parentTitle = "";  
       
       //----> check state of toggle button on app.view <-------------


          if (userRole != "") {
           if (userRole == "admin") {
            oTileUrl = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("adminUrl");
           }
           else if (userRole == "user") {
            oTileUrl = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("userUrl");
           }
          }

          window.open(oTileUrl, "_blank");
          
      }
     });

    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to do, but i'd advice **against** both of them:

- Models
- Parameter in your Navigation

Here are some links to get all the info you need on them:

- https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c
- https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d

Why I advice **against** both of them:

Both of them can *easily* be maniplulated via the comand line of a browser!
Anyone can take a look into you controllers, look up your model name or get the parameter for admins.
The only scenario where in which you could do that, is if you create some kind of secruity mechanic once the user hits those admin views/pages.
And with those mechnics I **do not** mean something like:

```
 if (userRole != "")
```

This too can be manipulated too easy within a Browsers console.

========================================================

Quick glance at models (my prefered way) if you are to lazy to read up on the sap site

App.view.xml:

```
<ToggleButton id="btnRoleSwitch"  
    icon="sap-icon://person-placeholder" 
    enabled="true" 
    pressed="{urModel/>isPressed}" 
    press="onRoleSwitchPress" 
    type="Transparent"/>
```

onInit of your component.js:

```
var oUrModel= new JSONModel({
            isPressed : null,
            .
            .
            .
        });
        this.setModel(oUrModel, "urModel");
```

view1 controller:

```
this.getView().getModel("urModel").getProperty("/isPressed")
```